# C ascii converter printf Extra integer

Tags: c, char, scanf, newline, conversion-specifier

Trying to create a simple C char to ASCII convertor

But the result print "10" after each printf.

Any Ideas to resolve that?

Compiler: mingw64/gcc

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    char argc;
    printf("Enter for ASCII: ");
    do {
        scanf("%c", &argc);
        printf("%d\n", argc);
    } while (argc != 'Z');
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./ascii.exe 
Enter for ASCII: A 
65
10
S
83
10
D
68
10
V
86
10
X
88
10
Z
90
```

Comment: The `10` is the decimal value for the newline character `'\n'`. It depends on what you want to do, but adding a space to your format string probably works: `scanf(" %c", &argc);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` with the format string `"%c"` reads all characters including white space characters as for example the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter. To skip white space characters you can either prepend the format string with a space like

```
    scanf( " %c", &argc);
           ^^^^^
```

The C Standard 7.21.6.2 The fscanf function

> 5 A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by
> reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains
> unread), or until no more characters can be read.

Or you can ignore it in the loop the following way

```
do {
    scanf("%c", &argc);
    if ( argc != '\n' ) printf("%d\n", argc);
} while (argc != 'Z');
```

Comment: Ohh Thanks for the answer. Is the quote
`std C 7.21.6.2 fscanf function`
is differs from scanf()?

Comment: @ycohui The description of scanf refers to the description of fscanf.